# multiple requests with recv() call

Tags: c, recv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Socket recv() hang on large message with MSG_WAITALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470403/socket-recv-hang-on-large-message-with-msg-waitall)

I am developing a webserver. For every new connection request I am spawning a thread. In the thread function, I am using recv() to receive requests.

```
    while (1) {ret = (int)recv(s, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_WAITALL);
    SYSLOG(LOG_USER, "s=%d recv returned with ret=%d\n", s, ret);
    if (ret == -1) {
        if (errno == 11)
            continue;
        else
            break;
    } else if (ret == 0)
        break;
...........   //handling the request
```

But, it servers only the first request and then the client (httperf) gets client-timeout error.
The recv() returns with return value -1 and errno EAGAIN.
How to server multiple requests over the same connection?

Comment: How big is the buffer?  Also did you read what MSG_WAITALL does?

Comment: The buffer size is 4096 bytes.
This is the request from client:
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: httperf/0.9.0
Host: localhost

Also, i tried with flag 0 in the recv() call. But, the same result repeated.

Comment: well there you go then, `MSG_WAITALL` on SOCK_STREAM sockets will block until 4096 bytes are ready for consumption.  In man page words (you should read it): On  SOCK_STREAM  sockets  this  requests that the function block until the full amount of data can be returned.

Comment: try `MSG_DONTWAIT` instead of `MSG_WAITALL`...

Comment: tried MSG_DONTWAIT, but still only one request is received. Then recv() is returning with return value -1 and errno 11.
The request is sent from the httpref like this:
httperf --hog --server localhost --port 81 --num-conn 1 --num-calls 2  --timeout 5 --burst-length=1
The result:
Errors: total 1 client-timo 1 socket-timo 0 connrefused 0 connreset 0
Errors: fd-unavail 0 addrunavail 0 ftab-full 0 other 0

Comment: errno 11 is `EAGAIN`, which is an expected error for non-blocking socket operations. It simply means "there's no data available right now, try again later". In this case, just proceed as usual, as if `recv` has not been invoked in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but there is supposed to be a data as the client is making two requests and also since the client exited with timeout error, it means its second request is not received by the server. My problem is that i(my programming logic) am not receiving all the client's requests. The question is, how can i receive all the requests for a particular connection?

Comment: @vikas: I tried your code (with no flags in recv()), a blocking socket, and no threads.  It works as expected, the issue must be on your side.

Comment: Thanks hroptatyr for that effort. I modified my code to make it without thread. Still it is receiving only one request. I am writing the entire code:

Comment: I am not able to paste all the code in the comment box. How can i paste the code here ?

Comment: I figured out that unless i close (?) the socket for first request, the httperf is not sending the second request. This i figured out by closing the connection after serving first request. Then the error from httperf is 'connection close' for second request. But since i am waiting for all requests (in this case 2) per connection i am not closing the socket after responding to first request and hence the httperf is throwing client timeout error. How do i finish with first request without closing the socket ?

Comment: I am using select loop on the accepted connection to server all the requests for that connection. BUt i am receiving only one request from the connection. Why am i not able to receive other requests? where am i loosing them?

Comment: see [Socket recv() hang on large message with MSG_WAITALL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8470403)